# How to import Vuex store in typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex

So I was working with Vuex in typescript, and I kept having to deal with one issue constantly (and while this issue could be just as easily fixed by changing the file from ts to a js file, I wanted to know how could I make it work in ts)

So my store file looked like this:

```js
    // store/index.js
     
    import Vue from "vue";
    import { createStore} from "vuex";
    
    const store = createStore<state>({
        state: {
            isOpen: false,
        },
        mutations: {
            toggleSidebar() {
                isOpen = !isOpen;
            }
        }
    });
    
    export default store;
```

```
        // main.ts file
        import { createApp } from 'vue'
        import App from './App.vue'
        import store from '@/store'
        
        const app = createApp(App)
        app.mount("#app")
        app.use(store);
```

The hierarchy for file structure is:

- main.ts
- store

  1. index.js

The issue I would get is "Could not find a declaration file for module '@/store'. '/home/saurav/Website/src/store/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type."

Comment: What is the reason for it to be .js and not .ts? You'll need to write .d.ts declaration otherwise

Comment: The reason is that when I was creating the app, I used the 'use Typescript' option (because I thought that writing in typescript will be better), and hence that created the one file in ts, but when I went to create the store/index in ts, it caused some issues and hence I named it index.js. Furthermore, the ts is causing a few more issues when trying to import the store in a .vue file

Comment: Then this is was a wrong decision. Whatever the issues were, consider addressing them instead of this error, because you can't use untyped js in ts project without extra efforts, this defies the purpose of using ts.